# How to string.splice time zone

Tags: javascript, string, react-native

I am using [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) to pick date and it works fine. For example, when I pick a date, I get something like this: `Mon Nov 05 2018 14:35:47 GMT+0900 (Korean Standard Time)`

But I am getting unnecessary values so I want to cut to `Nov 05 2018 14:35` using `string.splice` or `subString`.

Below is my code:

```
    import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
            class InfoScreen extends Component{
              constructor(props){
                super(props)

              this.state={
                datePick:'',
                }
              }

            _showDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true })

               _hideDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false })

               _handleDatePicked = (date) => {
                 console.log('A date has been picked: ', date);
                 this._hideDateTimePicker()
                 this.setState({
                   datePick:date
                 })
               }
             render(){

                return(
                  <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {this._showDateTimePicker()}}>
                  <Text style={{color:'gray',paddingTop:3, marginLeft:5}}> 
        //Here I get something like: Mon Nov 05 2018 14:35:47 GMT+0900 (Korean Standard Time)
                  {this.state.datePick.toString()}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <DateTimePicker
                           isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
                           onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked}
                           onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker}
                         />


    <Text> //I want to get new value here. Something like: Nov 05 2018 14:35
 {this.state.datePick.slice(4,7)}
    </Text>
                  </View>

                 )
               }
             }
```

I used `{this.state.datePick.slice(4,7)}` but not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `slice(4,7)` means that you are getting the substring from 4th index to 6th index. Also, Date object has no `slice` method, so you have to convert it to string first. Use `this.state.datePick.toString().slice(4,21)` to get the string with the same format as `Nov 05 2018 14:35` or `this.state.datePick.toString().slice(4,24)` to get the number of seconds too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment` package for formatting the dates instead of slicing them as we want and it is not the best approach as well.

```
npm install moment --save
```

For more please visit https://momentjs.com/docs/

```
import Moment from 'moment';

{Moment(this.state.chosenDate).format('MMM DD YYYY HH:mm')}
```

For showing how it works I use `DatePickerIOS`.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  DatePickerIOS,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'
import Moment from 'moment';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { chosenDate: new Date() };

    this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
  }

  setDate(newDate) {
    this.setState({chosenDate: newDate})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DatePickerIOS
          date={this.state.chosenDate}
          onDateChange={this.setDate}
        />
        <Text>
          {Moment(this.state.chosenDate).format('MMM DD YYYY HH:mm')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
})

//Nov 05 2018 14:35
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite late answer but still,

```
toDateString()
```

who is still loking for the answer.